# How to specify starting serial number

Tags: acumatica

I have a serialised item. The serial number is tracked during receipting. The serial class is configured as follows :

[image]

When the item is serialised, during receipting. I'm supposed to generate the serial numbers starting from a seed value e.g. KL89000.

[image]

When I clicked the Generate button however, it's giving me blank serial numbers.

[image]

Isn't that the whole point of "Start Lot/Serial number" ? Am I missing something else in my configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider adding LotSerialSegment details to your SerialClass as shown below.
[Although not shown] you can also choose to "Share auto-increment between all Item Class items" and specify the auto-increment value (89000) to begin.
When setting up a StockItem using SERIAL2, you can specify its Auto-Increment value [if not sharing].  Your next Receipt will handle the LotSerialNbr assignment for the Qty specified.

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QCnm.png